# List.Sort() throws An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll - C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a Person type list and it has some items and I want to sort this list by default(without any params). So I have used person.Sort() method.
When I execute the code I get an exception writes

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll

at Sort() method.
Any experts please explain the reason behind.

```
List<Person> person = new List<Person>();
person.Add(new Person() { Name = "crank arm", Age = 1234 });
person.Add(new Person() { Name = "chain ring", Age = 1334 });
person.Add(new Person() { Name = "regular seat", Age = 1434 });
person.Add(new Person() { Name = "banana seat", Age = 1444 });
person.Sort();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your `Person` class implement `IComparable`

The sort methods throws that exception when

> The default comparer Comparer.Default cannot find an implementation of the IComparable generic interface or the IComparable interface for type T.

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Person is your defined class, Sort method do not know how to compare between Person objects, you need to implement the comparison method, you can refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas(v=vs.110).aspx